# Accessing an element in a slightly complicated dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import requests
api="https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest"
response=requests.get(api)
local_case_tracker=response.json()
print(local_case_tracker.items())
print(local_case_tracker['data'])
print(local_case_tracker['data']['regional'])
```

So I'm trying to build a Covid tracker(global and local, and by local i mean my own country) using python.If you run the code you get to see a really big and branched dictionary and I wish to access any one of the states in that dictionary (lets say Goa) but i cant do so, so I tried to break down the problem by doing  this

```
print(local_case_tracker['data'])
print(local_case_tracker['data']['regional'])
```

Im able to fetch some results but  when i try

```
print(local_case_tracker['data']['regional']['loc : Goa'])
```

i get a:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Its a very stupid doubt but ive been scratching my head over this since the last 30 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`local_case_tracker['data']['regional']`is a Python List (of Dictionaries) so should be accessed by index, stepping through by or searching through. Try this to get the data for Goa.

```
for item in local_case_tracker['data']['regional']:
    if item['loc'] == 'Goa':
        print(item)
```

You could just save the item instead of printing it; it is a Dictionary so could access the values using the various keys. Also try this to see all the locations

```
for item in local_case_tracker['data']['regional']:
    print(item['loc'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much... this is not my real code , the real one is big and uses tkinter , over there i couldn't access the states so i created a separate python file(scratch file as they call it on pycharm) to check where i was going wrong.

Comment: Glad to help. If you use for example `print(type(local_case_tracker['data']['regional']))` then you can check the type of each level so you then know how to access the next level.

Comment: Sure,  and thanks  for the additional tip, ill keep that in mind.